# Why is my layout looks like it shrunk when I use additional kv file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to learn how to use multiple kv files in one project. But I ran into this issue:
Here's the [screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CGOq.png) of my issue.

.py

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Builder.load_file("cm_dd_btns.kv")

kv = """
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: hex("#07074D")

    DD:
"""

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


MyApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<DD@MDBoxLayout>
    cols: 1
    spacing: 1
    orientation: "vertical"

    Button:
        text: "First btn"

    Button:
        text: "2nd btn"
```

I tried modify the size of the layout and widget in both the files. But it's not making both buttons visible.

Can someone explain how to fix this and why this is happening?

Comment: Found no issues with your posted code !

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @ApuCoder. Have you seen the screenshot I added? There suppose to be a two buttons on the window, instead there's only one and even that button isn't properly displayed.